# Updating table with self reference in Postgres updates more entries than supposed to

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table with questions that reference same table on parent questions.

Doing a SELECT query for all row entries for column `title` displays all of that questions as Query 1/Result 1 pair below.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT t_child.title AS t_child_title, 
    t_child.question AS t_child_question, 
    t_child.parent_qid AS t_child_parent_qid, 
    t_child.language AS t_child_language, 
    t_parent.title AS t_parent_title, 
    t_parent.qid AS t_parent_qid, 
    t_parent.language as t_parent_language
FROM lime_questions AS t_child JOIN lime_questions AS t_parent
ON t_child.parent_qid = t_parent.qid AND t_child.language = t_parent.language
WHERE t_child.title = 'SacroCoccix';
```

**Result 1:**

```
 t_child_title |   t_child_question    | t_child_parent_qid | t_child_language | t_parent_title | t_parent_qid | t_parent_language 
---------------+-----------------------+--------------------+------------------+----------------+--------------+-------------------
 SacroCoccix   | Sacro e/ou Cóccix     |               1095 | pt-BR            | lisCortAt      |         1095 | pt-BR
 SacroCoccix   | Sacrum and/or coccyx  |               1095 | en               | lisCortAt      |         1095 | en
 SacroCoccix   | Sacrum and/ or coccyx |               1078 | en               | lisFxAt        |         1078 | en
 SacroCoccix   | Sacro e/ou Cóccix     |               1078 | pt-BR            | lisFxAt        |         1078 | pt-BR
 SacroCoccix   | Sacro e/ou Cóccix     |               1056 | pt-BR            | lisCortPr      |         1056 | pt-BR
 SacroCoccix   | Sacrum and/or coccyx  |               1056 | en               | lisCortPr      |         1056 | en
 SacroCoccix   | Sacro e/ou cóccix     |                973 | pt-BR            | lisFxPr        |          973 | pt-BR
 SacroCoccix   | Sacrum and/or coccyx  |                973 | en               | lisFxPr        |          973 | en
```

Adding the filter `t_parent = 'lisFxPr'` to the query the results are restricted to the question parent title `lisFxPr`, as the pair Query 2/Result 2 below.

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT t_child.title AS t_child_title, 
    t_child.question AS t_child_question, 
    t_child.parent_qid AS t_child_parent_qid, 
    t_child.language AS t_child_language, 
    t_parent.title AS t_parent_title, 
    t_parent.qid AS t_parent_qid, 
    t_parent.language as t_parent_language
FROM lime_questions AS t_child JOIN lime_questions AS t_parent
ON t_child.parent_qid = t_parent.qid AND t_child.language = t_parent.language
WHERE t_child.title = 'SacroCoccix' AND t_parent.title = 'lisFxPr';
```

**Result 2:**

```
 t_child_title |   t_child_question   | t_child_parent_qid | t_child_language | t_parent_title | t_parent_qid | t_parent_language 
---------------+----------------------+--------------------+------------------+----------------+--------------+-------------------
 SacroCoccix   | Sacro e/ou cóccix    |                973 | pt-BR            | lisFxPr        |          973 | pt-BR
 SacroCoccix   | Sacrum and/or coccyx |                973 | en               | lisFxPr        |          973 | en
```

I want to UPDATE only the 2 lines displayed in **Result 2**.

I'm running the following query:

```
UPDATE lime_questions t_main SET title = 'SacrumCoccyx'
FROM lime_questions AS t_child 
JOIN lime_questions AS t_parent
ON t_parent.qid = t_child.parent_qid AND t_parent.language = t_child.language
WHERE t_main.title = 'SacroCoccix' AND t_parent.title = 'lisFxPr';
```

But, this UDPATE query updates all the 8 entries displayed in **Result 1**.

What I'm missing please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE syntax:

```
[ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] with_query [, ...] ]
UPDATE [ ONLY ] table [ [ AS ] alias ]
    SET { column = { expression | DEFAULT } |
          ( column [, ...] ) = ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) } [, ...]
    [ FROM from_list ]
    [ WHERE condition | WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name ]
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

You can try this query.

```
UPDATE lime_questions AS t_main 
SET title = 'SacrumCoccyx'
FROM lime_questions AS t_parent
WHERE t_main.title = 'SacroCoccix' AND 
t_parent.title = 'lisFxPr' AND 
t_parent.qid = t_main.parent_qid AND 
t_parent.language = t_main.language;
```

Comment: The first alternative ('You can try this query') results in `ERROR: column "t_main" of relation "lime_questions" does not exist`. `LINE 2: SET t_main.title = 'SacrumCoccyx'`

Comment: Second alternative ('or update with an alias name') results in `ERROR: relation "t_main" does not exist`. `LINE 1: UPDATE t_main`.

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot @D-Shih. Hours trying to do that.

Comment: @Caco No problem :)